# Insertion Sort Strings

Tags: java, string, sorting, insertion-sort

I read a file with cities and its population and I am trying to sort the cities alphabetically using an insertion sort.
The issue is that it sorts all of the elements except the first one. The first value in the unsorted list remains in index [0] in the sorted list. This is the code:

```
    int i, j;
    String v;
    for (i = 1; i < cities.size()-1; i++)
    {
        v = cities.get(i);
        j = i;
        while (cities.get(j-1).compareToIgnoreCase(v) > 0 && j >=2)
        {
            cities.set(j, cities.get(j-1));
            j--;
        }
        cities.set(j, v);
    }
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: `for (i = 1; i < cities.size()-1; i++)`??  Java arrays are zero indexed...Any reason why you're not using `Collections.sort`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this...

```
for (i = 1; i < cities.size()-1; i++)
```

should probably be...

```
for (i = 1; i < cities.size(); i++)
```

Second, this...

```
j = i;
```

should probably be...

```
int j = i - 1;
```

Third, this...

```
while (cities.get(j - 1).compareToIgnoreCase(v) > 0 && j >= 2) {
```

is a mess.  You try and access the value from the `List` BEFORE you ascertain if the value is actually accessible (ie if `j` is within the range of the `List`) and probably should be something more like...

```
while ((j > -1) && (cities.get(j).compareToIgnoreCase(key) > 0)) {
```

Having said all that, this will mean that `cities.set(j, cities.get(j - 1));` will need to become `cities.set(j + 1, cities.get(j));` and `cities.set(j, v);` will need to become `cities.set(j + 1, key);`

Something like...

```
    List<String> cities = new ArrayList<>(25);
    cities.add("D");
    cities.add("C");
    cities.add("B");
    cities.add("A");

    for (int i = 1; i < cities.size(); i++) {
        String key = cities.get(i);
        int j = i - 1;
        while ((j > -1) && (cities.get(j).compareToIgnoreCase(key) > 0)) {
            cities.set(j + 1, cities.get(j));
            j--;
        }
        cities.set(j + 1, key);
    }
```

for example...

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, but the issue was in the condition. It should be in reverse order like this:    j > 0 && cities.get(j-1).compareToIgnoreCase(v) > 0

Comment: I tried that originally, but it didn't seem to work, some I reworked the entire code

Answer (score 3):

You probably want `for (i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++)`.

Accessing arrays and lists starts counting from 0, but the actual size of the list/array starts counting from 1.

Example: To access the first (and only) element of an array `a` of size 1, you would use `a[0]`.

Comment: I can't start with i = 0 because j = 0 and I compare an element that is in index [j-1].